# What's the best way to store irregular areas of my map? (hierarchical pathfinding and grid segmentation)

Tags: path-finding, tilemap, grid, roguelikes, hierarchy

This is for the development of a roguelike/management game.

I'm trying to implement HPA (hierarchical pathfinding with A*), and I've found a few good resources (suggestions appreciated) in the forms of:

- [Rimworld's Technology Overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMBQn_sg7DA)
- [Songs Of Syx Pathfinding for 30K entities](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anGdYJu_eH4)
- [Archived Implementation Article](https://web.archive.org/web/20190411040123/http://aigamedev.com/open/article/clearance-based-pathfinding/)

Something not mentioned in most of the resources (other than the Rimworld Tech Overview), is the need for splitting the super-grid if it is split up by things like walls. If there is a wall running through the center of a grid cell, then the cell needs to be split in two.

Sometimes these wall shapes will mean that the grid will need to have irregularly shaped sizes, and I'm having difficulty deciding how to store these irregular shapes.

Here are my thoughts when it comes to approaches:

- Some kind of grid-polygon? This would make intersection checking a pain.
- A list of tiles that make up the chunk, this would be quite slow
- Just use squares, this would mean that a lot of useless squares are created.

I just want to make sure I'm not missing something obvious here. I feel like I've been so close to this problem that an outside opinion would be very helpful.